# Serialization of XML Document (System.InvalidOperationException)

Tags: c#, xml

I'm attempting to setup my first export/import of a list to/from an external XML file. Upon start I have the following code:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Temp"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Temp");
        if (!File.Exists("C:\\Temp\\mygames.xml"))
            File.Create("C:\\Temp\\mygames.xml").Close();
        //Call method to read data from XML to List<>
        videogame = ReadFromXmlFile<List<vglist>>("C:\\Temp\\mygames.xml");
        displayList();
    } // END of method Form1_Load
```

With the ReadFromXmlFile method as follows:

```
    public static T ReadFromXmlFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
    {
        TextReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        } // end try
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
        } // end finally
    } // END ReadFromXmlFile<T> method
```

But I keep getting the following error upon execution of the program:

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Xml.dll

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).

My class is set up as follows:

```
public class vglist
{
    [XmlElement("gameName")] // XML tag
    public string GameName // game field
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
etc...
```

Any ideas? I've search everywhere with similar problems but no solutions which are helping.

Comment: Please post the XML (or near example) as that may also be relevant to discovering any parsing issues.

Comment: The XML file which I'm trying to populate is created upon start up, but it never populates by the time I reach the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if the file does not exist, your creating a new blank XML file. I suspect your error is due to the XML file containing nothing.

Comment: The XML file mygames.xml is indeed blank. From what I gathered, the initial code at the start is just to create the file if it doesn't exist, and then once it does, it'll populate the XML file with the data entered from the program.

Comment: @Madrical you are correct, but the snippets you have provided only show reading, no writing. Here's MSDN link for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656715.aspx